# Entity groups in dialogflow cx

Tags: dialogflow-cx

How would you approach a problem where a user can order multiple objects which each can have entities associated

For example with a user utterance
"I want to order a large pizza with pepperoni and a small pizza with ham and pineapple"

I would want to
Recognise two distinct pizzas
The different size for each pizza
The topping associated with each pizza

I know Rasa has an option called entity groups which can handle this but does dialogflow cx? Or is it better to design a conversation flow that manages the conversation in a way that doesn't allow this sort of input?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use a form parameter in your page collecting your pizza order. You can see in the [form parameter documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#form) that there's a boolean option for each parameter of the form named `isList` that collects multiple instances of a particular entity type you specify, which in your case I assume it would be the entity `pizza`.

Answer (score 0):

For the example your provided ("I want to order a large pizza with pepperoni and a small pizza with ham and pineapple"), you can use numerical indexes in the [intent parameter](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#intent) names in the training phrase [annotations](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/intent#annot).

The annotations may look like this:

[image: pizza intent]

Numerical indexes will allow you to understand how many pizzas were ordered.

Extracted parameter values for this annotation will look like this:

[image: pizza test]

For this proof of concept, the fulfillment is defined as [conditional response](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment#cond):

[image: pizza conditional response]

You can define more sophisticated dynamic responses in your [webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/webhook).

Note that if you opt for this approach, you will need to add multiple diverse training phrases and annotated all of them consistently. Check out [agent design best practices](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent-design).

An alternative approach – collecting parameter values one by one via required [form parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#form) – has various advantages:

- you don't need to add and annotate training phrases
- parameter value extraction may be more accurate.

In form parameter prompts, you may need to instruct the end-user to responds with only one piece of information at a time.